# How can I configure nginx?

Tags: nginx

After installing nginx I can see that the homepage of my web server is changed with the default nginx page. How can I configure nginx now?

Comment: configure nginx to do what exactly? See http://wiki.nginx.org/Install and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Nginx

Comment: I want to run nginx along with my LAMP server. I need to configure it to work. Now I am getting just the nginx default page when I go to http://localhost without being able to see the index.php page and other pages...

Comment: We need more information. run with LAMP how ? to do what? php, static content, proxy ?

Comment: I had installed LAMP on  my ubuntu box. And then I have created a website and put it on the /var/www directory. After that when I go to localhost the web page shows properly. Then I heard about nginx which is like a caching software optimize website speed. Then I installed nginx from launchpad ppa. After that when I go to localhost it shows the default nginx page. I am now not able to open any of the pages of my website. When I try to open one the nginx default page comes.

Comment: what is in /var/www now ? nginx is a web server, as is apache, and configuration in /var/www is the same for apache as nginx.

Comment: as far as I can see that /var/www is now showing Welcome to nginx! And i really dont know the configuration  of apache and nginx for the folder /var/www is same or not. I want to make nginx work as a caching system under apache web server.

Comment: Both apache and nginx see files, such as index.html or index.php the same. http://serverfault.com/questions/30705/how-to-set-up-nginx-as-a-caching-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx is a light weight and fast web server also you can use nginx fastcgi cache options to   speedup your websites.

To configure nginx first you have to add set no of option in nginx like server_name and root path

You can try [easyengine](https://github.com/rtCamp/easyengine/) which install and configure nginx and all the dependency on one go.

Sample Config For Your Nginx is: https://github.com/rtCamp/easyengine/blob/master/usr/share/easyengine/nginx/php/basic.conf